# Sharing folders revokes user permission

Tags: windows, network-share, file-sharing, user-permissions

I am currently trying to move files from server A to server B. 
Server A is currently hosting a website, and server is suppose to host it in the future. 
Server A has a severe firewall, connection through port 445 has been opened, but that still does not allow files to be shared across the servers using fileshare,

The only way, we've been able to move files som A to B, is by right clickking each folder -> enable share -> and give our users read/write permission.

A problem with doing this, is that enabling sharing of folders seem to revoke users that are in the permission list => thereby causing havoc on server A, and on the content it is hosting.

Is there a way to enable share, without revoking users permission given to the folder, or subfolders?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quit clear.
What is the purpose to share a folder if you do not give permissions?

Either you can give permission to everyone,group or a user, this is how folder sharing is working.

What i'm suggesting is to arrange all folders under 1 generic folder and share the generic one, this way you can handle only 1 folder and not share one folder by one.

Comment: Problem with doing this, is that the sub folders do have different NTFS permissions, I tried to sharing  a folder yesterday which incidently resulted in the IIS_USER was revoked its user permission on one of the subfolder resulting in a web app going offline..

Comment: You can change the subfolders sharing permission by enter to the share `properties` and then go to `advance` and for the permissin you want just add the `inherit` bit